# Can't complie SCSS after updating to OS X 10.13

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, compass-sass

I've bee unsing Dreamweaver and Koara to compile scss files by compass.

But since I updated my Mac to OS X 10.3 (HighSierra) I got those error messages.

`` Users/MyAccount/Desktop/test/sass/mtnCommon.scss
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:319:in `to_specs': Could not find 'compass' (>= 0) among 15 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/MyAccount/.gem/ruby/2.3.0:/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0', execute `gem env` for more information
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:328:in `to_spec'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:65:in `gem'
    from /Applications/Koala.app/Contents/Resources/app.nw/bin/compass:17:in `
' ``

Please let me know how to solve this.

Comment: reinstall your CLIs in terminal. The paths changed in the updated os and the application has no idea where its dependencies went.

Comment: Thank you. But I have no idea how to do it as OS X comes with `ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin15]` .

Comment: Open your project settings and navigate to the Compass tab.  Is 'Use the System Compass compiler' option checked?

Comment: In Koala, I'd checked 'Use the System Compass compiler' option already.
Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps to fix this problem:

1. Open Terminal
2. Install Homebrew:

   **ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"**
3. Do not close Terminal. Open Mac Appstore and check Update, install all **XCode Command Line Tools** updates
4. Back to Terminal
5. Install Ruby:

   **brew install rbenv ruby-build**
6. Install SASS gem:

   **sudo gem install sass**

Answer (score 0):

I've asked on GitHub's compass issue, and I got a reply saying "Fix this issue from DW side.".

So I need to wait until next DW comes out. Until then, I'll compile manually.

If you're using Koala, please ask the developer.

Thanks for your help.